# How to do update if exist without creating a duplicate row in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update the table called "user_star_rate" if the row is exists, otherwise insert data into table. It works well, but it is creating a duplicate row when updating. I want to prevent this problem.

Here is my SQL code.

```
$rate = "INSERT INTO user_star_rate (email, product_id, rate_value) 
         VALUES ('$visit_email','$product_id','$rate_value') 
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rate_value = '$rate_value'";
```

Comment: you need to use a `SELECT` query to see the row exist, then perform `update` or `insert` accordingly

Comment: Are you sur the unique constraint is set in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query works when inserted date have any unique key, for example you are inserting values `(email, product_id, rate_value)` so there `(email, product_id)` should combination unique so first add `unique` key of both fields and then try `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Add Unique key, if you have not added

```
ALTER TABLE `user_star_rate` ADD UNIQUE `unique_key` ( `email`, `product_id` )
```

query seems fine

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be INSERT.. ON DUPLICATION KEY UPDATE

Refer this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for details

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((select count(*) from user_star_rate where emailid=@emailid)>0)
begin
//Update Query
end
else
begin
Insert query 
end
```

You can also Do With EXIST key Word

```
  if exists (select 1 from user_star_rate where emailid=@emailid)
    begin
    //Update Query
    end
    else
    begin
    Insert query 
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the row not exists then insert into it unless if exists then Update it

```
$rate = "If not exist (select * from user_star_rate where email='$visit_email' 
 and product_id='$product_id') begin INSERT INTO user_star_rate (email,
 product_id,rate_value) VALUES ('$visit_email','$product_id','$rate_value') end
 else begin UPDATE user_star_rate  set rate_value = '$rate_value' where
 email='$visit_email' and product_id='$product_id' end";
```